# .htaccess rules do not work on GoDaddy server

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

The following .htaccess stopped working a couple of months ago and I cannot figure out why.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard*$ index.php?view=dashboard [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^new-safar*$ index.php?view=new-safar [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^safars*$ index.php?view=safars [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^active-safars*$ index.php?view=active-safars [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pre-registration*$ index.php?view=pre-registration [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^safars/kun-safar/([0-9]+)/edit-registration/([0-9]+) index.php?view=edit-kun-registration&safarid=$1&kunregid=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^safars/kun-safar/([0-9]+)/new-registration index.php?view=new-kun-registration&safarid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^safars/kun-safar/([0-9]+)/new-pre-registration index.php?view=new-kun-preregistration&safarid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^safars/kun-safar/([0-9]+) index.php?view=kun-safar&safarid=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^oops index.php?view=oops [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register-yourself register-yourself.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^its-verification*$ its_verifications.php [NC,L]
```

For example, this url https://zadmin.colomboshabab.com/safars is giving a 404 Error.

The site is going through **cloudflare** but it was working earlier. It is hosted on a **GoDaddy** server.

Comment: Should work in theory, https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ agrees on that. But neither that nor we can possibly account for any unknown additional configuration a specific hosting platform might have in place. If you can, I would suggest you go enable rewrite logging, and analyze what is going on based on that.

Comment: And btw., whoever made this appears to have a strange understanding of what quantifiers do … `^home*$` - was it really the intention to match `hom`, `home`, `homee`, `homeee`, `homeeee`, etc. here? Kinda rather doubt hat.